# Issue with events in switch widget

Tags: android

Hello everybody

I'm facing the following problem, I have a fragment with two widgets a Switch and a Seekbar. I'm trying to execute a function when the Switch is Turn On and Off and also a method when the Seekbar it is tracking, both methods affect both widgets, for example suppose that we have a Dimmable Light, and we could Turn On or Off or also we could dim the light brightness this is the case of what I'm talking about.

I was trying to use the event

`setOnCheckedChanged` on the Switch widget, but the problem is that when I move the seekbar to change the Dim I have to change the check status of the Switch, and at the time to do it the widget fired again the setOnCheckedChanged event, so I got something like loop.

My question is, there is any way to conditioned the onCheckedChanged event to only be fired when the user actually touch the widget in the screen?

This is the code that I'm using:

```
sw_dimmable.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                pb_dimmable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String val = "0";
                if (isChecked) {
                    val = "100";
                } else {
                    val = "0";
                }
                new handleTurnOffOn(getActivity()).execute(val);
        }
    });
```

Code for the seekbar:

```
seekBar_dimmable.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        String val = "0";
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            pb_dimmable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            val = String.valueOf(seekBar_dimmable.getProgress());
            new handleLevelChange(getActivity()).execute(val);
        }
    });
```

And those events call this method:

```
public void LoadInputFields() {
    lb_dimmable_name.setText(deviceItemDimmable.getDeviceItemName());
    if(deviceItemDimmable.getDeviceItemDimmableStatus().equals("0") ){
        lb_dimmable_status.setText("Status: Off");
        sw_dimmable.setChecked(false);
    }else{
        lb_dimmable_status.setText("Status: On");
        sw_dimmable.setChecked(true);
    }
    String level = deviceItemDimmable.getDeviceItemDimmableLevel();
    if(level != null){
        Integer val = Integer.valueOf(level);
        seekBar_dimmable.setProgress(val);
    }else {
        seekBar_dimmable.setProgress(0);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advanced

This solve the problem based on the answer of

@once2go

```
 public void LoadInputFields() {
    lb_dimmable_name.setText(deviceItemDimmable.getDeviceItemName());
    if(deviceItemDimmable.getDeviceItemDimmableStatus().equals("0") ){
        lb_dimmable_status.setText("Status: Off");
        sw_dimmable.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        sw_dimmable.setChecked(false);
    }else{
        lb_dimmable_status.setText("Status: On");
        sw_dimmable.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        sw_dimmable.setChecked(true);
    }
    String level = deviceItemDimmable.getDeviceItemDimmableLevel();
    if(level != null){
        Integer val = Integer.valueOf(level);
        seekBar_dimmable.setProgress(val);
    }else {
        seekBar_dimmable.setProgress(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create listener not as method parameter but as object, f-e:

```
private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener own_listener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                pb_dimmable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String val = "0";
                if (isChecked) {
                    val = "100";
                } else {
                    val = "0";
                }
                new handleTurnOffOn(getActivity()).execute(val);
        }
    }
```

then in another widget listener which affect your first listener, set null listener, f-e:

```
seekBar_dimmable.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        String val = "0";
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
sw_dimmable.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null); // here is disable listener 
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
sw_dimmable.setOnCheckedChangeListener(own_listener); // here is enable listener 
            pb_dimmable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            val = String.valueOf(seekBar_dimmable.getProgress());
            new handleLevelChange(getActivity()).execute(val);
        }
    });
```

Hope its helps

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I solved the problem with part of your answer, I just need to use `sw_dimmable.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);` in the method `LoadInputFields()` and everything works as expected. Thanks again

Comment: I update my question with the solution for this, thanks again for your time

Comment: Actually you can vote my answer if its was helpful)) Seems to me its a reason of reputation of this service)Good luck